# Unable to use float with nth-child selector to get 2 of 3 anchors to the right of my page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a html page where I have 3 anchors in an ordered list.  the last two anchors need to be at the right of the page.  I understand the better way to do this involves using nth-child selectors.  I attempted to create 3 instances, one to specify each anchor and this failed.  I could get one of the instances to the right of the page but not two.  I tried, as you will see in my code, using '2n+1' but that also did not work.

I am a bit stuck and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/MwT6d/

Comment: Probably a silly question, but why don't you just assign a class to the edit and delete link?

Comment: I am trying to use CSS.  the classes would make it easier I agree but I want to understand css capabilities.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwT6d/7/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
div.content ul li { 
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}

[...]

div.content ul li a:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    float: right;
}
```

In this way you set to `float: right` just the last two children `<a>` of every `<li>`, and then you clear the float at every `<li>`.

Comment: This is much closer, thank you!  I now have 'deteleedit' showing up on the right.  I need edit to be first and then delete.  However, if there is also a way to get the space in between the two words it would look much better.

Comment: Then you should set `clear: right;` into the declaration of `div.content ul li a` :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hr7uz/1/

In your case, to use the nth-child selector I would do the following.

```
div.content ul li a:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

div.content ul li a:nth-child(n+2) {
  float: right;
}
div.content ul li{clear:right}
```

The rest of your CSS seems to work fine. I would then add some margins or padding to those links that were floated right and there you go.

Personally how I would do it I would set all the relevant links to float right, then set the first-child to float left. It's kind of like thinking about the problem backwards.